# Deleting all the content from the database

Tags: sql-server, delete

We want to clean a database (delete all the records) with around 25 tables and a size of around 650+ GB in production. We are currently using MS SQL 2016 Standard Edition with AlwaysON HA.

Is truncating all the tables the best option, if not what is the best and fastest way to do this?

What is the potential time it is going to take for cleaning approx 650 GB of data?

Answer (score 3):

Use DBCC CLONEDATABASE to generate a new copy without data, drop the original database an rename the generated clone.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to throw away 650+GB of Data?
In *Production*?
*Really*?

Truncate *is* the fastest way to empty an existing table ...   *as long as* you really are *emptying* those Tables and that the 650+GB you want to get rid of isn't just 2% of all the data in those tables!
In that case, delete is your only option.  It will be slower than truncate and it will take *locks*, which will impact your Application, if it's running at the time.

An even *faster* way to get a whole new set of "clean" Tables *might* be to create all new Tables (in a new Database) with the same *structure* as the old ones (but none of the data) and switch your Application to use that new Database instead.  At least with this option, you still *have* the 650+GB of data if and when the Users say "Oops! You deleted too much!".

Comment: It might sound a bit off but there are 10 similar databases (Shards) with an almost similar amount of data so we are talking about 6.5+ TB data being wiped off from Production! This is more like starting on a clean slate. Delete with the locks and impact takes a serious amount of time when dealing with 90Million rows in some tables. 
New set of databases will require the AlwaysON HA changes as well, we want to handle in internally rather than making config changes on Application side.

Comment: Clean slate?  Clean databases.  
Shut the Application down, trash the Databases, recreate clean ones, restart the Application.  Job done.  
Just cross your fingers the Users don't change their minds and want any of it back ....